# Randomly shuffling lines in multiple text files but keeping them as separate files using a command or bash script

Tags: bash, shuffle

I have several text files in a directory. All of them unrelated. Words doesn't repeat in each file. Each line has 1 to 3 words in it such as:

- apple
- potato soup
- vitamin D
- banana
- guinea pig
- life is good

I know how to randomize each file:

```
sort -R file.txt > file-modified.txt
```

That's great but I want to do this in over 500+ files in a directory and it would take me ages. There must be something better.

I would like to do something like:

```
sort -R *.txt -o KEEP-SAME-NAME-AS-ORIGINAL-FILE-ADD-SUFFIX-TO-ALL.txt
```

Maybe this is possible with an script that go through each file in the directory until finished.

Very important is every file should only randomize the words within itself and do not mix with the other files.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.txt" -exec ./helper.sh '{}' \;` where `helper.sh` would be a short script that does `sort -R "$1" > "${1%.txt}_random.txt"` This would create the new file as `filename_random.txt` using the original `filename` for each file passed to the script using your `sort -R` command.

Comment: Or you could just use `for fname in *.txt; do sort -R "$fname" > "${fname%.txt}_random.txt"; done` -- which would be simpler if only one level in a directory is involved. Either way is fine. The `find` approach allows a more complex match of files to include, but if you just need `*.txt` files from a single directory, the `for` is simpler.

Comment: @GeorgeG: I don't understand from your writing: Is your problem that you don't know how to loop over the files, or how to dynamically generate a suffix for the output file, or how to make it faster?

Comment: Thank you @DavidC.Rankin you solution was what I was looking for! :) Just Perfect!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Would it be possible to make new random lists but with only 20 of the 40 lines in txt?

Comment: Sure, just use `head -n20` for the 1st 20 lines or `tail -n20` for the last 20 lines. Pipe the results to `shuf` or `sort -R`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this one-liner:

```
for file in !(*-modified).txt; do shuf "$file" > "${file%.txt}-modified.txt"; done
```

Just loop over the files and shuffle each one in turn.

The `!(*-modified).txt` pattern uses `bash`'s [extended pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html) to not match .txt files that already have -modified at the end of the name so you don't shuffle a pre-existing already shuffled output file and end up with `file-modified-modified.txt`. Might require a `shopt -s extglob` first, though that's usually turned on already in an interactive shell session.

Comment: Yep, `shuf` is fine too. Since words don't repeat, `shuf` and `sort -R` would be identical.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Heh, I see you added a comment with the same approach while I was writing out this one. Edited to make it a tad smarter and add more detail.

Comment: Yep, but you took the time to write it up and I gave you the vote.